# How to compute the integral closure of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $I=(X^2+Y^2)\subset\mathbb{R}[X,Y], A=\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/I$. And $x,y$ denotes $X+I,Y+I \in A/I$ respectively.

I proved that $I$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$. So, there exists the quotient field of $A$ (denoted by $K$).

I need to compute the integral closure of $A$ in $K$ (denoted by $B$). I know that $y/x,x/y\in B$ because $(y/x)^2+1=(x/y)^2+1=0$. Since $x/y=-y/x$, we get $A[y/x,x/y]=A[y/x]\subseteq B$.

I believe that $B=A[y/x]$ but cannot prove the other inclusion. Tell me whether my expectation is true or false, and how to compute the integral closure?

Comment: $A =\Bbb{R}[X,iX]$ and $\Bbb{C}[X]$ is integrally closed

Comment: @reuns Very nice! Thank you. ($A$ is integrally closed because $A[y/x]\simeq\mathbb{R}[X,iX][i]=\mathbb{C}[X]$, isn't it?)

Comment: According to your notation $A$ is the polynomial ring. Did you mean that?

Comment: @Mohan Thank you for pointing it out. I fixed.